# Как можно получить из url https://moscow.tagil-steel.ru/ первое слово до точки?

Tags: php

Как можно получить из url https://moscow.tagil-steel.ru/ первое слово  до точки. Я хочу получить из url   слово `moscow`. Как это можно сделать. Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = 'https://moscow.tagil-steel.ru/ ';
$result = explode('.', parse_url($url)['host'])[0];
echo $result;
```